# Sending array with objects throw ajax to php

Tags: php, json, ajax

Help me please:
I create my object:

```
var data = [];

$("#report-container [id^='report-']").each(function(index) {
    var reportObject = {
        "subject" : "",
        "photo" : "",
        "rating" : "",
        "comment" : ""
    };
    reportObject.subject = $("#name-report-"+index).text();
    reportObject.photo = $("input[name='subject-photo-"+index+"']")[0].files[0];
    reportObject.rating = $("input[name='subject-rating-"+index+"']").val();
    reportObject.comment = $("textarea[name='subject-comment-"+index+"']").val();
    data.push(reportObject);
});
```

After this I have an array. I convert it to json like this:

```
var myarray = JSON.stringify(data);
```

if I console log it, it looks like this:

```
[{"subject":"Окна","rating":"0","comment":""},{"subject":"Пол","rating":"0","comment":""}]
```

And then I send it to php:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/report-data/add_report.php",
    data: { data: myarray },
    async: true,
    cache: false,
```

and in php I try to get it like this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
echo(json_encode("this".$data));
```

And it doesn't works...

Comment: put a success and an error function in the ajax callback and see which 1 is hit and also please show the error messages from the network tab

Comment: Doesn't work __how__?

Comment: `echo(json_encode("this".$data));` looks weird. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: i try to send what php recieves

Comment: Then you should just do a `var_dump($_POST)` and check the real response in the dev consoles network tab. You're actually changing the data with that json_encode() (since you're adding things to it).

Comment: And learn about callbacks at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this code you will find that your php variable $data is an array()

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
var_dump($data);
```

Then in the seconde line you have

```
echo(json_encode("this".$data));
```

whiche caused the error beacuase you can not concatenate string with an array `"this".$data` So try this simple changes.

```
echo("this".json_encode($data));
```

because `json_encode($data)` return a string than you can concatenate it with "this" wich is string